# how to add on off text to existing toggle switch

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to insert an ON/OFF text to my toggle switch. When the slider is switched on 'ON' text should be displayed and when the slider is off, 'OFF' text should be displayed. They should be displayed inside the toggle. Please help.

```css
.cm-toggle {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
    position: relative;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
}
.cm-toggle:after {
    content: '';
    width: 35px;
    height: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: rgba(196, 195, 195, 0.55);
    border-radius: 18px;
    clear: both;
}
.cm-toggle:before {
    content: '';
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
.cm-toggle:checked:before {
    left: 20px;
    box-shadow: -1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.cm-toggle:checked:after {
    background: #3895D3;
}
```

```html
<input class='cm-toggle' type='checkbox' checked>
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/XavierSpruce/pen/emoNqa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```css
.cm-toggle {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
    position: relative;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
}
.cm-toggle:after {
    content: '';
    width: 35px;
    height: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: rgba(196, 195, 195, 0.55);
    border-radius: 18px;
    clear: both;
}
.cm-toggle:before {
    content: 'off';
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.cm-toggle:checked:before {
    left: 20px;
    box-shadow: -1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    content: 'on';
}

.cm-toggle:checked:after {
    background: #3895D3;
}
```

```html
<input class='cm-toggle' type='checkbox' checked>
```

Comment: can we display text within the larger area,not on the round area

Comment: You can't do that with your current html setup, needs more elements. Take a look at these https://codepen.io/himalayasingh/pen/EdVzNL?editors=1010

Answer (score 0):

Add this

```css
.cm-toggle {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
    position: relative;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
}
.cm-toggle:after {
    content: '';
    width: 35px;
    height: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: rgba(196, 195, 195, 0.55);
    border-radius: 18px;
    clear: both;
}
.cm-toggle:before {
    /* Modification */
    content: 'OFF';
    text-indent: 38px;
    /* END */
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
.cm-toggle:checked:before {
    /* Modification */
    content: 'ON';
    text-indent: 18px;
    /* END */
    left: 20px;
    box-shadow: -1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.cm-toggle:checked:after {
    background: #3895D3;
}
```

```html
<input class='cm-toggle' type='checkbox' checked>
```

Comment: `They should be displayed inside the toggle.`

Comment: Well ... you can see it as an alternative ;-)